# DNN TabController.GetPortalTabs returns different results when initial request comes from a browser or a standalone program

Tags: c#, wpf, dotnetnuke

I'm creating an API to access content from DNN externally based on the DnnApiController.
One of the endpoints is supposed to return all the pages that the user has access to. The list of pages is populated with `DotNetNuke.Entities.Tabs.TabController.GetPortalTabs(PortalSettings.PortalId, -1, true, string.Empty, true, false, true, true, false)`

This works fine when the request originates from a browser or Postman client, but when the callers is a standalone application (in this case a a test WPF application) the results are wrong.

When called from a browser/postman, 10 tabs are returned but only 5 when called from WPF.

Any ideas whats going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got around this in the end by instantiating a new `TabController`, getting all the tabs in the portal then filtering as follows

```
var controller = new DotNetNuke.Entities.Tabs.TabController();
var tabs = controller.GetTabsByPortal(PortalSettings.PortalId)
    .Where(t => DotNetNuke.Security.Permissions.TabPermissionController.CanViewPage(t.Value))
    .Select(t => t.Value);
```

While this is less efficient as all the pages are now returned before being filtered it does work and the API won't be too heavily used so this isn't the end of the world.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that inside the GetPortalTabs function overload it is doing some processing based on the current user: UserController.Instance.GetCurrentUserInfo(). This method is looking at the HttpContext to get the current user.  It uses the current user to filter out tabs that the user has no permission to.  If calling from an external service, the HttpContext.Current would be null.  Therefore the tabs may be filtered by only tabs available to All User permission.

Comment: I did some more digging and that is indeed what is happening, but strangely the `UserInfo` property on the controller is correctly populated, so I'm not sure why it can't get the same information in the method call